# Can MediaPipe specify which parts of the face mesh are the lips or nose or eyes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mediapipe

MediaPipe is capable of providing the x,y,z points of multiple points on the face, enabling it to generate a face mesh. However, the output is just in x,y,z points. Is there any way to know which of those points are those of the lips?

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh

# For static images:
IMAGE_FILES = []
drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
    static_image_mode=True,
    max_num_faces=1,
    refine_landmarks=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_mesh:
  for idx, file in enumerate(IMAGE_FILES):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    # Convert the BGR image to RGB before processing.
    results = face_mesh.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    # Print and draw face mesh landmarks on the image.
    if not results.multi_face_landmarks:
      continue
    annotated_image = image.copy()
    for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
      print('face_landmarks:', face_landmarks)
      mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
          image=annotated_image,
          landmark_list=face_landmarks,
          connections=mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_TESSELATION,
          landmark_drawing_spec=None,
          connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
          .get_default_face_mesh_tesselation_style())
      mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
          image=annotated_image,
          landmark_list=face_landmarks,
          connections=mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_CONTOURS,
          landmark_drawing_spec=None,
          connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
          .get_default_face_mesh_contours_style())
      mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
          image=annotated_image,
          landmark_list=face_landmarks,
          connections=mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_IRISES,
          landmark_drawing_spec=None,
          connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
          .get_default_face_mesh_iris_connections_style())
    cv2.imwrite('/tmp/annotated_image' + str(idx) + '.png', annotated_image)
```

Output:

```
landmark {
  x: 0.5328186750411987
  y: 0.3934963345527649
  z: -0.008206618018448353
}
landmark {
  x: 0.5807108879089355
  y: 0.3586674928665161
  z: 0.017649170011281967
}
landmark {
  x: 0.5844370126724243
  y: 0.3515523076057434
  z: 0.01841720938682556
}
...and more such points
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import matplotlib `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

```
xVal = []; yVal = []; zVal = []
xS = []; yS = []
for land in results.multi_face_landmarks:
    print(type(land.landmark))
    count = 0
    for i in land.landmark:
      xVal.append(i.x)
      yVal.append(i.y)
      zVal.append(i.z)
      if count == 0 or (count >= 11 and count <= 17): #some points on the lip
        xS.append(i.x); yS.append(i.y)
      count = count + 1
    print("Total = ", count)
plt.scatter(xVal, yVal, color = 'blue')
plt.scatter(xS, yS, color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

The points on the face will match the points shown in this diagram. You'll have to download the image and zoom in to see the numbers.
[image]

Comment: hi, i'm pretty new, can i use those numbers for android also? or will it change depending up on image or pixel resolution

Comment: I don't know. That's why I plotted the points and tried to verify for myself. You could plot it too and see.

Answer (score 1):

Nav's answer is good and creative. but you can also use the official medaipipe framework `canonical_face_model_uv_visualization`. download [this image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/mediapipe/master/mediapipe/modules/face_geometry/data/canonical_face_model_uv_visualization.png) from mediapipe repository and zoom image to explore landmarks.

Answer (score 0):

In the official repo, if you go into mediapipe/python/solutions/face_mesh_connections.py you would see the symbols plane on the right hand side which would specify which landmark indices are plotted for each component of the face mesh.

[Reference SC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2NhP.png)

In the attached image you can see lips as the first title in symbols panel.

[Git link](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/7c28c5d58ffbcb72043cbe8c9cc32)